# CloudSQL DR Solution Backup/Restore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I’m a bit new to Cloud SQL and I was reading the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups?hl=vi#where_backups_are_stored) but stuck into this

> MySQL Second Generation instances: Backup data is stored in two
>   regions for redundancy. If there are two regions on a continent, the
>   backup data remains on the same continent. However, you cannot restore
>   an instance from a backup in a different region if the instance’s
>   region is unavailable

So let's imagine that I’m running Cloud SQL with mysql Second Generation instance in europe-west1 with HA layout. Backups data are also replicated in europe-west2 for redundancy (same continent). If europe-west1 is entirely offline can I create a new Cloud SQL instance (on europe-west3 for example) and restore my database?

I’m trying to figure out the best way to handle multi-region DR with Cloud SQL since there is no cross-region replica

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer how to handle multi-region DR with Cloud SQL since in the accepted answer it is said that Cloud SQL HA is between two zones of the same region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as the documentation states, you won’t be able to restore from a backup if the instance’s region is offline.

Being unable to restore the database from the backup doesn’t mean not having access to the Cloud SQL data. Second Generation instances offer optional [High Availability configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability), allowing them to have a failover replica. When an instance is unresponsive, Cloud SQL automatically makes the data available from its failover replica in another zone of the same region.

Comment: Failover replica is in another zone of the same region, not another region.

Comment: @David my mistake, the documentation is pretty clear in that regard. I've corrected it, thanks for pointing it out!